# Is there any physical explanation for the synthetic Landau levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-optics

Apparently, synthetic Landau levels are formed in light which exhibits orbital angular momentum in a resonator. This was shown by this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07381. There's a part which states that the modes of light are projected onto a cone which I don't completely understand. Is there any explanation for this since there are no charges or magnetic fields like in the "non-synthetic" Landau level?

Comment: It is a little tough to see what your question is. Is it basically "How can there be Landau levels in a system that's not a 2d electron gas in a magnetic field?"

Comment: Yes @d_b. That is the question. Thanks.